# By the time we arrive there, it will have already be 7 o'clock/later than 7 o'clock. - which is more idiomatic?

Tags: modal-verbs, conjunctions, time

**Example 1**

> It is too late now. By the time we arrive there, it will have already been **7 o'clock.**

**Example 2**

> It is too late now. By the time we arrive there, it will have already been **later than 7 o'clock.**

Which one is more idiomatic?

I think Example 2 probably is more idiomatic because it is more broad and it is hard to get there and it happens to be 7 o'clock sharp.

**Example 3**

> It is too late now. By the time we arrive there, it will have already become later than 7 o'clock.

Is this one correct, too?

I always feel that "become" can convey the idea of changing better than a be-verb.
But I am not certain. Can anyone shed light on this?

Comment: None of those is correct. "It will be after/past seven o'clock." We never say "it will have been [a certain time]" or similar.